# Why is there Ignoring deprecated use of DefaultType?

Tags: .htaccess, server, xampp

I have wrote the following code on .htaccess file but whenever i load php file, it shows this message why.

```
Options +MultiViews
DefaultType application/x-httpd-php
Options -Indexes
ErrorDocument 403 /403
ErrorDocument 404 /404
```

Comment: it seems that `DefaultType` is no longer supported, see here: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/fr/mod/core.html#defaulttype

Comment: "it shows this message" - what message?

Comment: it shows this -> "Ignoring deprecated use of DefaultType" message. Lol @MrWhite

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`DefaultType` isn't just *deprecated*, it's been *disabled* in Apache 2.3+. As [stated in the docs](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#defaulttype):

> This directive has no effect other than to emit warnings if the value is not `none`.